# Why did I need to specify a specific class to import in python?

Tags: python

I just upgraded to Python 2.7.1 (on Mac) so I could use OrderedDicts.

After trying to run the following script:

```
import collections

test = OrderedDict()
```

I got:

```
NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined
```

I fixed it with:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

...but I want to know why I needed to do that?

Why didn't the broad `import collections` work for me?

Comment: Read this: http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
import collections
```

imports the collections module into the current namespace, so you could work with this import like this:

```
import collections
orderedDict = collections.OrderedDict()
```

However, if you only need a specific function (and not the entire library), you could do this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

imports just the specified class into the current namespace.

Comment: You can explore what is happening in an interactive python session:
1. start an interactive python session
2. call the builtin function: globals()
3. import something 
4. call the builtin function: globals()
5. have a look at the changes

Answer (score 4):

You can do `import * from fooModule` but it's bad juju and makes Guido cry.

For a brief explanation of why it is the way it is, `import this`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it goes like this:

When you do `import collections`, you’re actually assigning the module “collections” to a variable called `collections` in the current namespace.

At this point, you can access the `OrderedDict` class inside the collections module using `collections.OrderedDict`.

What `import collections` *doesn’t* do is assign any other variables in the local namespace. Specifically, it doesn’t automatically assign a variable to everything within the collections module (although, as [noted in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710029/why-did-i-need-to-specify-a-specific-class-to-import-in-python/5710169#5710169), you can do this explicitly).

As to *why* it doesn’t do this, I think it stems from item two in *The Zen of Python*: “Explicit is better than implicit.”

Comment: You are exactly right.  It all comes down to namespaces and scoping.

Comment: @jathanism: phew, I was hoping I still had a handle on it. I like Python because it takes a few concepts, and gets a lot of mileage out of them. Makes stuff like this easier to remember/deduce.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way Python works. Originally you just imported the module and it made the "collections" namespace available in your module with the name "collections". To reference anything in that module you must qualify it as `collections.OrderedDict`. The `from` form pulls an object reference from the module into your module namespace so you don't need to qualify it.